# Print a message in try/with block without return value in Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm writing a test unit for a basic-didactic interpreter in OCaml, so I have tests that return a valide expressive value (evT) and tests that simply fail, and "throw" a failwith("something") statements.

If I compile and run the file, obviously at the first failwith the program terminate. So I'm using a try/with block to prevent this happening and continue with the test process. I just want to print the error message without return any value, BUT it continue to say that expect an expressive value instead of an unit.

Here a snippet from my code:

```
try
    eval (Dict([("",Eint(30));("mele",Eint(40))])) myEnv
with
    Failure(msg) -> Printf.printf "%s" msg
;;
```

And this is the output:

```
404 |     Failure(msg) -> Printf.printf "%s" msg
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type
         evT
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the value returned by `eval` you can just ignore it:

```
let _ : evT = eval (Dict([("",Eint(30));("mele",Eint(40))])) myEnv in ()
```

But then what are you really testing? Just that it doesn't throw? Shouldn't you also check that the result is correct?

Alternatively, if you DO need the value outside the `try` block, then you're going to need a value in the case where you catch the exception as well, which is what the error message is essentially telling you. The only other option is to abort the program, which I understand you don't want.

Comment: I don't need the value returned by the eval function but I just want to check that, with a properly-crafted input, it throw an error. But, even with your solution, the program keep crashing when encounter the line.

Comment: Then it doesn't seem like you're catching the right exception.

Comment: Mmh I don't get the point. I just want to do something like `try something catch print("message")` and go on with the other tests.

Comment: You can catch all exceptions by using the wildcard pattern, `_`, instead of `Failure(msg)`.

Comment: The "line" should be inside the try, not around it: `try let _ : evT = ... in () with Failure(msg) -> Printf.printf "%s" msg`. A probably better approach would be `try let _ : evT = ... in TestFailure("evaluation didn't throw an exceptioN") with Failure(msg) -> TestSuccess`